# What does "Mounted from blah" mean for docker push command?

Tags: docker

I noticed a strange log statement in our build logs, that seems to only show up the first time a particular image is built. I couldn't find any reference to it in Docker literature. I'm interested in knowing what it means.

```
The push refers to a repository [mycompany.com:5000/blah]
a35c50f48e25: Preparing
// more preparing
0c3170905795: Waiting
// more waiting
47a9d8491623: Mounted from foo
e856ece746ae: Mounted from foo
f2ec1bba02a6: Mounted from bar
6407c62d4add: Mounted from foo
0c3170905795: Mounted from bar
df64d3292fd6: Mounted from bar
5ed59af669b0: Pushed
a35c50f48e25: Pushed
```

What this "Mounted from foo" mean in the above log, and why does it only show up the first time?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This indicates that the specified layers you want to push to that repository do not exist in that repository, but they do exist in another repository on the same registry server which you have read access to. Instead of transferring the layers over the network, docker shares the layers between the repositories.

This change was introduced in the [2.3 registry release](https://github.com/docker/distribution/releases/tag/v2.3.0) and is referred to as Cross Repository Blob Mount.

Comment: I believe the layer in question exists in several other repos that I've access to. Can you tell which one is chosen in that case?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar it will show you which one is used (foo/bar). The selection of which repository is probably an implementation detail, but shouldn't really matter, it should be the same layer that those two repos already share for the same reason.

Comment: This feature should speed up push over network but the truth is opposite: it slows down push dramatically.

Comment: @SerG do you have a reference to a github issue or other public post detailing the scenario where you encounter performance issues?

Comment: Just the [Issue](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2988) I created yesterday. I specified no technical details because I'm not sure which exactly needed. I hope some docker developer could ask anything really helpful if it's really uncommon case.

Comment: What happens when one of the mounted images get deleted?

Comment: You have one less reference to the content. The garbage collector cleans up content when there are no references to it remaining.